# Странное поведение VIM при редактировании файла

Tags: macos, vim

Всем привет,

На всякий случай, MacOS Catalina. Пытаюсь отредактировать любой текстовый файл при помощи VIM, но получается это сделать только частично.

К примеру, я могу создать файл с нуля, закинуть какой-то текст в него и сохранить - всё ОК.

Я могу открыть в VIM любой существующий файл, добавить в него текст и сохранить - всё ОК

Но я не могу изменить уже существующий текст - попытка удалить хоть один уже существующий символ вызывает System Bell.

Я не могу понять, это бага или я нахожусь в каком-то режиме, который всеми силами защищает существующий текст ? Если второе, то как отключить эту фичу ?

UPD: добавил более детальное описание проблемы:
Vim в терминале, стандартном для MacOS. Пытаюсь удалить текст путём Backspace в режиме вставки, но удалить получается только тот текст, который я только что закинул. После сохранения файла новый текст тоже станет невозможно убрать, к примеру:

1) создаём файл #vim 123

2) переходим в режим вставки (i), пишем текст: 123123123123123123123123

3) нажатием backspace можем удалить текст без каких-либо проблем.

4) пишем любой другой текст, к примеру 234234234234234234234

5) сохраняем и выходим wq!

6) открываем файл заново #vim 123

7) переходим в режим вставки (i)

8) пытаемся удалить что-то из текста (234234234234234234234) и ничего не выходит.

9) можем вставить символы в существующий текст, то есть, привести текст к виду 234234234!!!!!!!!!!!!!234234234234

10) при этом мы можем удалить восклицательные знаки в тексте, пока не сохранимся и не выйдем из Vim.

11) сохраняемся и выходим: wq!

12) открываем файл заново #vim 123

13) текст 234234234!!!!!!!!!!!!!234234234234 изменить уже не можем. Только вставить в него символы, например: 234234234!!!!!!!!!!!!!23423????????4234234

Comment: Vim в терминале? Как вы пытаетесь удалить текст?

Comment: Если не работает backspace/delete это признак плохо настроенного терминала. Хотя я такого уже лет 10 не встречал.

Comment: Добавил более подробное описание проблемы. Да, Vim в Терминале, стандартном для MacOS. Настройки Терминала дефолтные. Nano работает полностью без проблем

Comment: А вы vim как-то настраивали? Попробуйте `:set nocp bs=2`

Comment: Никак не настраивал (по крайней мере этого не делал я), но :set nocp bs=2 - получилось в рамках одного сеанса vim

Comment: Ну значит это надо добавить в .vimrc и стоит прочитать про них справку

Comment: Да, я так и сделал и всё заработало. Действительно надо почитать :) всё как-то было без надобности. Спасибо ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Починилось путём внесения изменений в конфиг:

```
user@Macbook~ % cat ~/.vimrc 
syntax on
 set nocp bs=2
```

Comment: Я бы поменял эти строки местами. Вообще `set nocompatible` (`set nocp`) рекомендуется писать самой первой т.к. эта опция неявно меняет кучу других опций.

Comment: Поменял, спасибо